# can you explain this python django makemigrations error?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration

I deleted my database and when I tried to migrate with a new database I am getting this error.

traceback

```
 File "D:\work\Student Management\student_management_system\student_management_app\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views, AdminViews, StaffViews, StudentViews
  File "D:\work\Student Management\student_management_system\student_management_app\views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .AdminViews import *
  File "D:\work\Student Management\student_management_system\student_management_app\AdminViews.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .forms import *
  File "D:\work\Student Management\student_management_system\student_management_app\forms.py", line 8, in <module>
    class AddStudentForm(forms.Form):
  File "D:\work\Student Management\student_management_system\student_management_app\forms.py", line 19, in AddStudentForm
    for course in courses:
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\work\Student Management\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "student_management_app_courses" does not exist
LINE 1: ...student_management_app_courses"."updated_at" FROM "student_m...
```

I don't understand what the error is.

Comment: Can you add AddStudentForm to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form `AddStudentForm` in the file "student_management_app/forms.py" you are executing a query when your app is initialised. This prevents migrations from working correctly because the migration process has to setup your app to run and you can't (shouldn't) run queries before any tables have been created.

Most likely you are creating choices for a form field, you need to remove this query and replace it with a ModelChoiceField that is passed a queryset that is not executed